# Minimal Client For SSH'ing into Remove Server

Tags: ssh, remote-access, thin-client

I'm thinking of using a virtual private server as my daily workstation. I'm experimenting with mostly using terminal to try and do significant amounts of work. Don't read too much into that, I'm weird.

I'd love a minimal way to SSH into a remote server. I understand how easy it is to use something like putty on windows, or ssh command on linux computer, but ideally I don't want a client computer at all. Almost like a kvm switch that still allows me to SSH into a remote machine.

I'm basically trying to make a modern terminal. I looked a bit at IP-KVM switches but those seem to require hooking a device physicall to the server. Other solutions like Dell's DRAC are similar.

I'm looking for a dumb, bulletproof way to connect to remote systems that doesn't involve having two distinct computers to worry about (client and server), I'm trying to get to having pretty much just a 'server' and a zero-client that I can remote into it with.

Any ideas? Is SSH the wrong idea here? Is this impossible?

Comment: What you are asking for is to extend your keyboard & mouse from the rs to where ever you are. The answer is no as that would still require some system to handle the IP traffic which would require a computer system, even as small as a sbc. I would also question why you would want a rs to do all your work on if your access system is just as, if not more powerful than the rs, since they tend to all be shared in someway, limiting your expected processing power.

Comment: I understand that at some level there will always be two ‘computers’ involved, but I’m trying to get my local one to be a dumb, immutable input/output type of machine as much as possible.

Comment: Then install a sbc and strip it down such that when the kernel boots, it will call your ssh command after bringing up the network.